# Deploy pods in different nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a namespace called `airflow` that has 2 pods: `webserver` and `scheduler`. I want to deploy `scheduler` on node `A` and `webserver` on node `B`.

[image: nodes & pods]

And here you can see deployment files:

scheduler:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: airflow
  name: airflow-scheduler
  labels:
    name: airflow-scheduler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow-scheduler
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:        
        - name: scheduler
          image: 123423.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/airflow:$COMMIT_SHA1          
          volumeMounts:
          - name: logs
            mountPath: /logs          
          command: ["airflow"]
          args: ["scheduler"]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "3072Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: "2048Mi"
      volumes:
          - name: logs
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: logs
```

webserver:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: airflow-webserver
  namespace: airflow
  labels:
    run: airflow-webserver
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: airflow-webserver
---    
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: airflow-webserver
  namespace: airflow
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - airflow.awesome.com.br
      secretName: airflow-crt
  rules:
    - host: airflow.awesome.com.br
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: airflow-webserver
              servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: airflow
  name: airflow-webserver
  labels:
    run: airflow-webserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: airflow-webserver
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - name: webserver
          image: 123423.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/airflow:$COMMIT_SHA1
          volumeMounts:
          - name: logs
            mountPath: /logs          
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          command: ["airflow"]
          args: ["webserver"]
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "200m"
              memory: "3072Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
              memory: "2048Mi"              
      volumes:
          - name: logs
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: logs
```

What's the proper way to ensure that pods will be deployed on different nodes?

edit1:

`antiaffinity` is not working:

I've tried to set `podAntiAffinity` on `scheduler` but it's not working:

```
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: name
            operator: In
            values:
            - airflow-webserver
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Comment: Specific node: nodeSelector field in the pod spec, just _different_ nodes: anti-affinity rules.

Comment: @johnharris85 could you help me with anti-affinity? I'm doing something wrong, check edit please

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have these pods run on different nodes but you don't care about which nodes exactly, you can use the *Pod anti-affinity* feature. It basically defines that the pod X should not run on the same node (it can be also used with failure domain / zones etc., not just with nodes) as pod Y and uses labels to specify the pods. So you will need to add some labels and specify them in the `spec` sections. More info about it is in [Kube docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

If in addition you want to also specify on which node it should run, you can use the *Node affinity* feature. See [Kube docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) for more details.